# Continuous pointwise orientation

Tags: differential-topology

Lee defines an orientation on a smooth manifold $M$ as a continuous pointwise orientation.

A pointwise orientation (that is, a choice of orientation on each tangent space of $M$) is said to be continuous if every point of $M$ is contained in the domain of a oriented local frame (= a local frame with positively oriented basis throughout the domain); we call such a domain a *frame domain*.

I am a bit confused about this definition. Since each manifold is locally diffeomorphic to the Euclidean space, is it not vacuous that each point is in a *frame domain*? Simply take the coordinate domain.

I would appreciate an example. Can you help me understand why continuity breaks for the Mobius band? There must be a point which does not belong to a frame domain, according to this definition.

Edit: In general, I have difficulties to understand why one would define a (global) orientation in this way.

Comment: See my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4517356.

Answer (score 1):

I elaborate a bit on Toby Bartels answer:

Clearly, a smooth atlas gives a pointwise orientation via the coordinate vector fields, however, these may not be oriented (as local frames).

More precisely, for every $p \in M$ and (centered) coordinate chart $(U_p, \phi_p)$, we can choose the orientation of $T_p M$ to be the coordinate vector fields $$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_p^1}{\big\vert_{p}},  ..., \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_p^m}\big\vert_{p}\right\} =: \mathcal{U}_p,$$
where $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_p^i} := \phi^{-1}_{p\ast}(e_i) \in \Gamma(TU_p)$ and $e_i$ is the $i$th standard coordinate vector of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Now, fix $p \in M$. Then, for every $q \in U_p$, the ordered set of vectors $(\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_p^1}{\big\vert_{q}},  ..., \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_p^m}\big\vert_{q})$ defines a basis for $T_q M$. However, one should note carefully that the orientation of $T_q M$ is determined by the tuple $\mathcal{U}_q$. So, it is meaningful to ask whether these two tuple belong to the same equivalence class, or in other words, agree in orientation. Whenever they do, then $\mathcal{U}_p$ is indeed an *oriented* local frame for $p \in M$, but, of course, it may happen that they do not agree. Similar holds for any other point of $M$.

So, saying that a pointwise orientation is continuous means essentially that the local orientations induced by $\{\mathcal{U}_{p}\}$ "patch together".

**Addendum:** It turns out that each coordinate frame constitutes an oriented local frame (with respect to the point-wise orientation induced by the coordinate charts) if and only if the transition functions are orientation-preserving.

In the abstract setting, then, we allow

- any choice of orientation for each $T_p M$, rather than the one induced by the atlas,
- any local frame, rather than the coordinate vector fields.

How one goes about showing with this definition that the Möbius band is non-orientable, I still do not know.

Answer (score 0):

Because every manifold is locally Euclidean, you can define an orientation on a neighbourhood of any point, using a local coordinate frame, as you say.  But this definition is saying something more.  It's saying that you first orient every tangent space, and then you check that each point has a frame around it *that agrees with this previously chosen orientation of every tangent space*.  So on a Möbius band, for example, there's no special nonorientable point; but if you orient every tangent space, then there must be a point where the orientation is discontinuous.

To say this with some symbols:  First you have a pointwise orientation $ o \colon ( P \in M ) \mapsto ( o _ P \in \mathcal O T _ P M ) $, where $ T _ p M $ is the tangent space at $ P $ and $ \mathcal O V $ is the two-element set of orientations of a vector space $ V $.  Then you check that for each point $ P $, for some neighbourhood $ U $ of $ P $, there is a continuous frame $ e \colon ( Q \in U ) \mapsto ( e _ Q \in \mathcal B T _ Q M ) $, where $ \mathcal B V $ is the set of oriented bases of a vector space $ V $; such that for each $ Q $ in $ U $, $ e _ Q $ is positively oriented relative to $ o _ Q $.

Although saying it this way depends on knowing what a continuous frame is, so I think that it's better to say that each point has a coordinate chart around it that makes this work for the coordinate frame, since the coordinate charts are more fundamental (and automatically continuous, since they define the topology).  So after defining $ o $, you check that for each point $ P $, for some coordinate chart $ \phi \colon U \to \mathbb R ^ n $, for each $ Q $ in $ U $, the basis $ ( \phi _ Q ^ * ( \mathbf e _ i ) ) _ { i = 1 } ^ n $ is positively oriented relative to $ o _ Q $, where $ \phi _ Q ^ * ( \mathbf e _ i ) $ is the pullback of the $ i $th standard basis vector $ ( 0 , \ldots , 0 , 1 , 0 , \ldots , 0 ) $ of $ \mathbb R ^ n $ to $ T _ Q M $.  This is what it means for $ o $ to be continuous at $ P $.

Comment: When you say that the orientation is discontinous, do you mean that the map $\phi: M \to \{-1, +1\}$ which factors through the frame domains, i.e. $\phi(p) = \det(E_1\vert_p, ..., E_m\vert_p)$ where $(E_1, ..., E_m)$ is a local frame on a neighbourhood $U$ of $p$, is non-constant (assume, $M$ connected)?

Comment: And yes, what is a continuous frame? The vector fields that make up the local frames, are continuous. Is this what you mean?

Comment: When I say that the orientation is discontinuous, I mean that there's a point $P$ where the requirement beginning ‘for each point $P$’ (in either the definition using frames, or the equivalent definition using coordinate charts) fails.  If that requirement is met for a particular point $P$, then the orientation is continuous at $P$.  If it's met for every point $P$, then the orientation is continuous, which is what you want.

Comment: And yes, that's what it means for a frame to be continuous.  But notice that, just as we don't usually consider a pointwise orientation to really be an orientation unless it's continuous, so we also don't usually consider a pointwise frame (that is a map assigning a basic of the tangent space to each point) to really be a frame unless it's continuous (and even differentiable, or smooth for smooth manifolds).  So the definition that you read, didn't mention that the frame has to be continuous; that's already understood.

Answer (score -1):

Around a point in a manifold, there always exists a pointwise orientation and a local frame domain around that point, by using the coordinate domain. But this is not what we are interested in. We want **one** **global** pointwise orientation such that there is a local frame domain around each point.

You can't give me one global pointwise orienation on the möbius band, because the twist changes the orientation discontinuously along the "glued" sides. The möbius band is not orientable.

Comment: What is a global pointwise orientation?

Comment: an orientation for every tangent space of every point in your manifold. Your chart give two orientations on a coordinate domain. The challenge is, that all these local orientations need to "match up globally". This does not work on the möbius band continuously